# my Get method return some fields as null while the GetById method returns everything

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Currently working on my first web api and my first c# project, I've been stuck trying to implement the Get method.

In my project, an user can have a profession (Journalist, Developer, ...) and a profession field (Sports, Business, Website development, ...).

When I'm trying to get all the users, the profession (UserProfession) and profession field (UserProfessionField) attributes are returned as null. When I'm trying to return one user only by its id, those same attributes are not null anymore.

I have the following model for User:

```
namespace Sims.Models
{
    public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            DataUsages = new HashSet<DataUsage>();
        }

        public long IdUser { get; set; }
        public int UserProfessionId { get; set; }
        public int UserProfessionFieldId { get; set; }
        public string? UserName { get; set; }
        public string? UserMail { get; set; }
        public string? UserCompany { get; set; }
        public byte[]? UserPicture { get; set; }

        public virtual Profession UserProfession { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ProfessionField UserProfessionField { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ICollection<DataUsage> DataUsages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the DTO I'm using for this model:

```
namespace sims.DTO
{
    public partial class UserDTO
    {
        public long IdUser { get; set; }
        public string? UserName { get; set; }
        public string? UserMail { get; set; }
        public string? UserCompany { get; set; }
        public virtual ProfessionDTO UserProfession { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ProfessionFieldDTO UserProfessionField { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

Then there is my Get method and its result:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UserDTO>>> GetUsers()
{
    var users = _context.Users.ToList();
    var userDtos = new List<UserDTO>();
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        userDtos.Add(new UserDTO 
        { 
            IdUser = user.UserProfessionId, 
            UserName = user.UserName, 
            UserCompany = user.UserCompany, 
            UserMail = user.UserMail, 
            UserProfession =  user.UserProfession == null ?
            null as ProfessionDTO : new ProfessionDTO
            {
                IdProfession = user.UserProfession.IdProfession,
                ProfessionName = user.UserProfession.ProfessionName
            },
            UserProfessionField = user.UserProfessionField == null ?
            null as ProfessionFieldDTO : new ProfessionFieldDTO
            {
                IdProfessionField = user.UserProfessionField.IdProfessionField,
                ProfessionFieldName = user.UserProfessionField.ProfessionFieldName
            }
        });
    }
    return userDtos;
}
```

```
[
  {
    "idUser": 2,
    "userName": "user_test",
    "userMail": "mail@test.com",
    "userCompany": "TestCompany",
    "userProfession": null,
    "userProfessionField": null
  },
  {
    "idUser": 1,
    "userName": "roger_federer",
    "userMail": "feder@fedex.ch",
    "userCompany": null,
    "userProfession": null,
    "userProfessionField": null
  },
  {
    "idUser": 3,
    "userName": "rafa_nadal",
    "userMail": null,
    "userCompany": null,
    "userProfession": null,
    "userProfessionField": null
  }
]
```

And the GetById method and its result:

```
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserDTO>> GetUserById(long id)
        {
            UserDTO User = await _context.Users.Select(user => new UserDTO
            {
                IdUser = user.UserProfessionId,
                UserName = user.UserName,
                UserCompany = user.UserCompany,
                UserMail = user.UserMail,
                UserProfession = user.UserProfession == null ?
                    null as ProfessionDTO : new ProfessionDTO
                    {
                        IdProfession = user.UserProfession.IdProfession,
                        ProfessionName = user.UserProfession.ProfessionName
                    },
                UserProfessionField = user.UserProfessionField == null ?
                    null as ProfessionFieldDTO : new ProfessionFieldDTO
                    {
                        IdProfessionField = user.UserProfessionField.IdProfessionField,
                        ProfessionFieldName = user.UserProfessionField.ProfessionFieldName
                    }
            }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(user => user.IdUser == id);
            if(User == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                return User;
            }
        }
```

```
{
  "idUser": 1,
  "userName": "roger_federer",
  "userMail": "feder@fedex.ch",
  "userCompany": null,
  "userProfession": {
    "idProfession": 1,
    "professionName": "Journalist"
  },
  "userProfessionField": {
    "idProfessionField": 1,
    "professionFieldName": "Sports"
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea what could be the origin of this issue ?

Comment: can you please share your Context class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your data model, `UserProfession` and `UserProfessionField` are stored in separate tables; for both there are so-called Navigation properties on your `User` class. When using Entity Framework, these Navigation properties can be eager and lazy loaded. The earlier fetches the values directly with the parent object, the latter fetches them on demand.

In your `GetUsers` method, the first statement loads all the data from the database using a `ToList` - this breaks the ability to lazy load. Only after this, the projection using the `Select` takes place, but at this time, the data cannot be lazy loaded anymore.

In contrast in `GetUserById`, the call to `FirstOrDefaultAsync` follows the projection with the `Select`. During the `Select`, by accessing the `UserProfession(Field)` property, you lazy load the corresponding data from the other tables.

This explains why the behavior is happening. In order to fix this, you should change from lazy loading to eager loading for performance reasons (if you load 20 users and load the dependent data for each of them, you have 41 requests whereas with eager loading, you only need one). You can use the `Include` method for this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UserDTO>>> GetUsers()
{
  var users = _context.Users
    .Include(x => x.UserProfession)
    .Include(x => x.UserProfessionField);
  // ...
```

Above code includes the information in the `UserProfession` and `UserProfessionField` tables directly when loading the `Users`.

In addition, you can also change the `GetUserById` to also include the properties - though the performance problem is not as dramatic as with loading the list.

Comment: Ok that was the solution ! I thought about ``` Include ``` earlier but I had other issues and it wasn't the solution at the time and didn't try this again. 

Your explanation is very useful and easy to understand. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest

- You stop copy/pasting code around. Write a single function to transform a User database object into a User data transfer object and *call it* in both places.
- Start listening to your compiler warnings. You are comparing things to `null` that acording to your database can never be null. You are *assigning* `null` to things that cannot be null by your definition. Why isn't your compiler throwing errors like crazy? Did you turn that off? Why? Listen to your compiler.
- Test your code in isolation. Maybe with unit tests. If you cannot do that, at least ensure that you restart your whole app and your call under test is the first call made.

So when you have a single place where you transform a user object, with probably less code, then you can start looking for mistakes. Taking away the option of anything being cached, you should be able to find your mistake soon.

I don't know how your context is configured, but with the default configuration, you seem to be missing the `.Include`s for your navigation properties. They might be filled accidentially, because you called other code on the same context before. But even if that is the case, please take the three points above and fix them. This is no way to program.

Comment: I agree with you, copy/pasting isn't the best and I'm trying to do as much as I can by myself but as I'm just a beginner and don't find that many online ressources to learn about this. But I totally agree with you :)

I'm testing the application everytime I can and I'll check for the compiler warnings I promise ! Indeed, ```.Include``` was the solution in that case and I thought about that earlier when having another issue. I just didn't think about trying it in that case.

Thanks for the advice and help :)